# Foriegn Key from multiple tables on a single column EF code First

Tags: entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

I am using EF version 6.1 and have a mapping problem:

```
class BasePoco 
{ 
   public Guid Id{get;set;}
}
class Student : BasePoco
{
    public string Name;
}
public class UserBase : BasePoco
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
}
public class UserDetail : UserBase
{
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
}
public Enum UserType
{
  Student = 1, 
  User=2
}
```

the Attendance class

```
public class Attendance 
{
   public class UserId {get;set;}   // Can be either student or user
   public UserType UserType {get;set;}
}
```

I need to mark attendance for Student as well as User in the same table.
The UserType would determine whether the Id is of a student or User and the primary key would be a combination of UserType and Id.

How can I accomplish this using EF code first approach.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry you cant use multiple type over single property. You do understand, because EF run over metadata. Which use EF know metadata from model class. This is a problem. Attendance table foregin key is multiple table referance and Attendance model contains both model. You should create logical layer for check UserType and access correct model. For example

```
public class Attendance
{
public UserType userType {get;set;}

public Guid? UserId {get;set;}
public virtual User user {get;set;}

public Guid? StudentId {get;set;}
public virtual Student student {get;set;}
}
```

now layer class

```
public class AttendanceUserLayer
{
public static object GetUser(Attendance attendance) {
if (attendance.userType == UserType.User) {
return attendance.User;
} else {
return attendance.Student;
}
}
```

how to use

```
Attendance attendance = context.Attendance.FirstOrDefault();
var userOrStudent = AttendanceUserLayer.GetUser(attendance);
```

if you cannot use the type of object result, write interface both class and set return type that interface.